# Harvest specific dataset with Harvester?

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu-14.04, ckan

With the CKAN Open Data Portal you can define a harvest job, which is a service that can collect data from various sources, and store it in your portal. One of the options is to harvest from another CKAN Source. I have managed to do so, but it the harvester collects ALL datasets on that remote instance, and that is overkill for what we need.

Is there any way to specify which datasets you want to harvest in CKAN, instead of getting all of the datasets with no exceptions?

Some metadata:
- Ubuntu server 14.04
- Python 2.7
- Newest version of CKAN (2.5?)
- Rabbit-mq message broker (can choose Redis if needed)

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to this is to use the `organizations_filter_include` option. See the [CKAN harvester docs](https://github.com/ckan/ckanext-harvest#the-ckan-harvester). On the source CKAN you'd need to put the datasets you want harvested into a particular organization(s).

That may not be convenient though, so you could so it with groups instead. That would require a bit of copy and pasting in ckanharvester.py to adapt the `organizations_filter_include` functionality. A Pull Request for this would be welcomed (and indeed mandatory if you run this change on a public site, according to the AGPL license).

The most flexible way would be to add a new harvester config option to specify datasets via a search string, which would be passed as `fq_terms` to `_search_for_datasets`. Again, this would be a welcome contribution.